How to mock different behavior from the same method call made in a loop
I’m new to Mockito and have a question.
Say I have a method:
SomeClass someMethod() throws SomeException{};

and, its called in a loop:
for(int i=0; i < 2; 1++) {
    try {
        SomeClass someObject = someMethod();
    } catch(SomeException e) {
        //. Do something
    }
}

When mocking, I know we can separately mock the execution of the method for a call that returns a SomeClass object successfully, as well as mock an exception scenario:
Successful result:
when(someMethod()).thenReturn(new SomeClass());

Exception:
when(someMethod()).thenThrow(new SomeException());

My questions is:
How would I mock the someMethod() method call, so that on one invocation it successfully returns a SomeClass object while on the other invocation it, throws a SomeException?
Basically, in order to get code coverage for both successful and exception scenarios in:
for(int i=0; i < 2; 1++) {
    try {
        SomeClass someObject = someMethod();
    } catch(SomeException e) {
        // Do something
    }
}

I hope this makes sense!  Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

just do the when...then in the loop

@Antoniossss I would think that the loop is inside the tested code, so you cannot reconfigure the mock inside that loop. Is that correct, @SandeepBarnabas?

Why? I think it would just work.

I would not test "happy path" and "exception path" in one single test. Makes it harder to determine, which part went wrong in case the test doesn't pass.

But that is different story - so it would work ?:>

@Antoniossss No, using mocks in production code doesn't "work" - for any reasonable definition of the word.

Who says its in app code?

You can chain the thenReturn/thenThrow calls like this:
when(mock.someMethod()).thenReturn(new SomeClass()).thenThrow(new SomeException());

The first call to mock.someMethod() will return a SomeClass object, the second will throw a SomeException
For more information, refer to the docs.
